# Attempting to access property on JavaScript Object = Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JavaScript object

```
Object {VoteTag: Object, ResortVoteTag: Array[1]}
  ResortVoteTag: Array[1]
   0: Object
   id: "1"
   resort_id: "1561"
   tag_id: "4"
   user_id: "31"
   vote: "3"
   length: 1
 VoteTag: Object
   id: "4"
   tag: "Snowboarders"
   type: "slopes"
```

I'm trying to access the vote property in the ResortVoteTag array however I am unable to do so.

This is the following code I'm using.

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/Votetags/alltags",
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json', 
            }).done(function ( data ) {
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                        console.log(data[i].ResortVoteTag.id);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Probably want `data[i].ResortVoteTag[j].id` (where `j` is another loop iterator). Your description of the object includes two Array definitions. (though i have to say that way of describing an object is confusing...)

Comment: Your browser has a fully-featured debugger built into it. Set a breakpoint on the first line of your `done` function and look at the data you're receiving.

Comment: T.J. is right, or you just console.log(data) and look at it in console.

Answer (score 2):

`data` is an object, based on your example data, and `ResortVoteTag` is the array. So you need to iterate over that specifically.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.ResortVoteTag.length; i++){
    console.log(data.ResortVoteTag[i].id);
}
```